# Does the new StackExchange toolbar display UTC time anywhere?

Tags: support, top-bar

With the old toolbar, one could see the current UTC time; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10975/39599). Is that feature still present somewhere in the new toolbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bars icon, where the reputation and achievements are shown.

On the top-right corner.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post a screenshot right now. I might do it later.

Comment: Top left corner?

Comment: Top right corner of the Achievements drop-down.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks. My comment was about the location of the Achievements drop-down itself. It did not cross my mind that Asaf was referring to the top right corner of the drop-down box itself.

Comment: @Michael: I kinda thought this part would be relatively obvious. I suppose that you got upvoted/downvoted at least once since the top bar was introduced.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Good point.