# What constitutes a day for the purposes of daily limits?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

There is a daily limit of 200 rep for things like upvotes on answers. What constitutes a day though? Is it a rolling 24 hour period? 12:00am to 12:00am GMT? Something similar with my own time zone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the standard time maintained by MSE?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/what-is-the-standard-time-maintained-by-mse)

Comment: @GrigoryM I think this is a different question. Just because the standard time is UTC doesn't tell you if/when a rolling interval is used for limits, if a fixed interval is used that starts at 0:00, or at 6:00, etc.

Comment: Oh, guess you're right, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on the particular limit.

For  reputation and badges, the UTC day is used (0:00-23:59 UTC time). See [What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27199) For other reputation-related rules, see [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237)

Rate-limiting, such as the limit on the number of questions asked, is based on a  rolling period. That is, the daily limit for questions is 6 questions in *any 24 hour period*. See [Time reset/ending time for "Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 6 questions in a 24 hour period"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107726)
For more information in rate-limiting, see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899). Did you know that you can change your Winterbash hat only **once every 10 seconds**?

Answer (score 3):

[Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), in particular the UTZ zone (essentially GMT). (See [this previous meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12250/8348) for finding current UTC time within the new top-bar, or [go here](http://time.is/UTC).)

Comment: So is it 0:00 to 23:59?